# Can JavaFX UI icons be written/saved in a file and be retrieved later?

Tags: java, javafx, serialization

I am making a children's programming platform like [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu) using JavaFX. I have a series of commands, and when I click them they enter my "CodeBox" which extends the standard JavaFX class [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html). Of course, I want to add "save" and "resume" feature to my code. But as JavaFX objects are not [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), I am facing deep trouble.

To try, I have extended JavaFX Button class

```js
public class fButton extends Button implements Serializable{
```

And added another command to save that fButton object to a file, and the file seems to be written (in UTF-8):

```html
�� sr fButton׏aDN�� D  orgSceneXD  orgSceneYD 
orgTranslateXD 
orgTranslateYxp
```

I had another command to read a fButton from the file and add it to an existing VBox. When that command is executed, an empty button seems to be added, which does not contain the text or any other property of fButton.

Now I want to know if there is any way to save and retrieve all these objects or if there is a better way.

For your convenience, I am using JDK9.0.4 and IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.3. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: "another command"  - What commands did you use? Provide them.

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: don't save the controls, save their states

Comment: New to Java... My all other classes follow Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now I want to know if there is any way to save and retrieve all these objects or if there is a better way.

Serializing UI components in order to save state is generally a very *bad* way of doing things, as it creates an **insanely** close coupling between your UI and your application state.

What if you want to swap out a VBox for a custom StackPane component for instance in a future release? That's a very realistic scenario - perhaps you want to decorate those VBoxes for instance by overlaying some other component - yet doing so instantly wrecks anyone's ability to then load a file saved with a previous release.

I'd argue your backend state should be separated from the UI entirely - you can then serialize the backend state alone via whatever means you fancy (JSON, XML, some other Java serializer, etc.) and rely on your rendering / transformer layer to create the relevant components for your backend state.

You then decouple the two, allow for whatever serialization you like, and give much more scope for changing the UI layer without upsetting your backend model too much.

Answer (score 1):

For saving and loading I would recommend using JSON or XML files. Have a separate folder for images.  When you save the file, save the image file path. You can then attach the image or text when loading.

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setWrapText(true); //needed for text buttons
String imagePath = //this is the path to the image (save this)
Image buttonImage = new Image(imagePath);
        if (!buttonImage.isError()) {
            button.setGraphic(new ImageView(buttonImage));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Button` is not serializable and inheriting from it and implementing `Serializable` doesn't make it serializable. Then what happens when de/serializing `fButton`?

- at **serialization** : JVM just ignore value of inherited fields and serialize the default value. Which probably means in your case that the `String` used is serialized as `null`.
- at **deserialization** : JVM call the no-arg constructor for the non serializable inherited class. Which probably means in your case that the `Button` is initialized with empty string as label.

If you want to control the serialization, read about internal/external serialization to have a better control. Don't rely on default serialization in your case.